# Select where IN using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Hello I'm trying to use IN condition in LINQ.

I have the following query:

```
select * from unitphotos Where MarketingFileTypeID = 2
AND UnitTypeID in (Select UnitTypeID from unitTypes Where PropertyID = 1)
```

I think I can't make it in only one LINQ query, so I did this:

```
var listUnitTypes = (from ut in db.unittypes
                     where ut.PropertyID == propertyID
                     select new { ut.UnitTypeID }).ToList();
var getPropertyPhotos = (from up in db.unitphotos
                         where listUnitTypes.Contains(up.UnitTypeID)
                         select up).ToList();
```

However, it gives me a syntax error inside Contains(up.UnitTypeID): "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'anonymous type int UnitTypeID'

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What's your input? Does the `UnitTypeID` is stored as a string or as a number? I'd suggest to read about [Any](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: Are the relationships setup correctly? If so, you should be able to do a join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var getPropertyPhotos = (from up in db.unitphotos
                         where unittypes.Any(ut => ut.PropertyID == propertyID && ut.UnitTypeId == up.UnitTypeID)
                         select up).ToList();
```

I think this should work. Haven't tried it since I don't have the db though so ymmv.

Also, yours should work if instead of `select new { ut.UnitTypeID }` you just put `select ut.UnitTypeID`

Answer (score 2):

You have anonymous type here

```
 var listUnitTypes = (from ut in db.unittypes where ut.PropertyID == propertyID select new { ut.UnitTypeID }).ToList();
```

And then try to use it in Linq To Entity:

```
        var getPropertyPhotos = (from up in db.unitphotos
                                 where listUnitTypes.Contains(up.UnitTypeID)
                                 select up).ToList();
```

Seems like Linq to Entity won`t know what that type is.

So you can replace

```
 select new { ut.UnitTypeID })
```

with

```
 select { ut.UnitTypeID })
```

as @anakic sad before

And then create 1 query by Linq

```
var listUnitTypes = (from ut in db.unittypes where ut.PropertyID == propertyID select ut.UnitTypeID);

var getPropertyPhotos = (from up in db.unitphotos where listUnitTypes.Contains(up.UnitTypeID) select up).ToList();
```

By that you force Linq to Sql create complicated query that should be able to handle your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the way that you are approaching the problem forcing a sub-select is going to end up having you going back to the database more than you have to.  I don't have an IDE available right now to bang out the correct LINQ syntax, but why not change your approach from thinking in terms of a SQL sub-select to that of a JOIN?  Here is the SQL that I would start with and then translate that to LINQ:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM unitphotos p
  INNER JOIN unitTypes u
    ON u.UnitTypeID = p.UnitTypeID
        AND u.PropertyID = 1
WHERE p.MarketingFileTypeID = 2
```